# Are there any tools for automatically generating Java code for screen scraping

Tags: java, proxy, screen-scraping, auto-generate

Is there a way of browsing a web site through a proxy and autogenerating Java code (using HtmlClient) that can play back the requests?

Comment: Your title and question sort of mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your code generation needs are. Have you looked at Apache JMeter that records test cases through a proxy and also provides interfaces for you to generate your own data.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org). You can use the Selenium IDE to record a session, and then choose use the "Export" menu item to export it to Java tests. You can then use the [Java Client Driver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#using-the-java-client-driver) to run the tests.